# How can I compare each single day of last two weeks in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, php

I'm stuck, this job seems too complicated for me I hope in some goodness help here!

So this is my table `views`:

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|                time|
+---+--------------------+
| 1 | 2016-10-06 10:13:11|
| 2 | 2016-10-07 15:33:31|
| 3 | 2016-10-08 20:13:13|
| 4 | 2016-10-09 09:16:21|
| 5 | 2016-10-10 18:23:17|
| . |                 ...|
+---+--------------------+
```

I need to select in array the rows count of each day for the last 2 weeks and compare them (so I need to compare monday of current week and previous week).

So I tried:

```
SELECT 'last_week' AS week, COUNT(*) AS rows 
    FROM `views`
    WHERE `time` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL  6 DAY 
      AND `time` < CURDATE() + INTERVAL  1 DAY
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'previous_week' AS week, COUNT(*) AS rows 
    FROM `views`
    WHERE `time` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 13 DAY
      AND `time` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL  6 DAY;
```

But it counts rows of each weeks and not single days. 
Yes, I can add eg. `AND DAYOFWEEK(`time`) = 7;` to the query, but in this case I have to declared it for seven times.

Basically I need something like:

```
+---------------+--------------------+
|          week | 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7|
+---------------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|     last_week | 1| 5| 3|15|12| 1| 3|
| previous_week |10|15|34|22|55|78|99|
+---------------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Where 1 is Monday, 7 Sunday.

Comment: I would do the following:  Use `GROUP BY` to get the counts per day; use date arithmetic to find week number and day of week; check the results.  Then I would apply "pivoting" code to the the day of week across the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PRELIMINARY DATE MATH

Here are two expressions you need to understand

```
mysql> SET @this_past_monday = CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SET @prev_two_mondays = @this_monday - INTERVAL 2 WEEK;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CURDATE(),@this_past_monday,@prev_two_mondays;
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| CURDATE()  | @this_past_monday   | @prev_two_mondays   |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-10 00:00:00 | 2016-09-26 00:00:00 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GOAL OF THIS ANSWER

You need to combine two queries

- generate a temp table with the dates based on these two Mondays
- retrieve counts from `views` table based on these two Mondays

## QUERY #1

Generate all dates from Jan 1st last year to 1000 days later, extracting all dates spanning 2 weeks before this past Monday

```
SELECT dt FROM
(SELECT MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()) - 1,H*100+T*10+U) dt FROM
(SELECT 0 H UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) H,
(SELECT 0 T UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) T,
(SELECT 0 U UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) U
ORDER BY dt) A
WHERE dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
AND   dt <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
```

## QUERY #1 EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT dt FROM
    -> (SELECT MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()) - 1,H*100+T*10+U) dt FROM
    -> (SELECT 0 H UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) H,
    -> (SELECT 0 T UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) T,
    -> (SELECT 0 U UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) U
    -> ORDER BY dt) A
    -> WHERE dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND  - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
    -> AND   dt <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2016-09-26 |
| 2016-09-27 |
| 2016-09-28 |
| 2016-09-29 |
| 2016-09-30 |
| 2016-10-01 |
| 2016-10-02 |
| 2016-10-03 |
| 2016-10-04 |
| 2016-10-05 |
| 2016-10-06 |
| 2016-10-07 |
| 2016-10-08 |
| 2016-10-09 |
+------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CURDATE();
+------------+
| CURDATE()  |
+------------+
| 2016-10-11 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## QUERY #2

```
SELECT DATE(`time`) dt,COUNT(1) RowCount FROM views
WHERE `time` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
AND   `time` <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND
GROUP BY DATE(`time`);
```

## COMBINATION

`LEFT JOIN` Query #1 and Query #2

```
SELECT A.dt,IFNULL(B.RowCount,0) RowsCounted FROM
(SELECT dt FROM
(SELECT MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()) - 1,H*100+T*10+U) dt FROM
(SELECT 0 H UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) H,
(SELECT 0 T UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) T,
(SELECT 0 U UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) U
ORDER BY dt) A
WHERE dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND  - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
AND   dt <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND) A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DATE(`time`) dt,COUNT(1) RowCount FROM views
WHERE `time` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
AND   `time` <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND
GROUP BY DATE(`time`)) B
USING (dt);
```

## REASON FOR COMBINATION / LEFT JOIN

In the event there are no rows for a particular date, you want Query #1 to still show a date but present 0 as the number of rows

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

NOTE : I will leave the gory details of presenting the data in your capable hands

Comment: Really thanks for your time and this useful answer!

Comment: Why have ` + INTERVAL 0 SECOND`?  Sure, it turns a `DATE` into the equivalent `DATETIME`, but why is that needed?